# Redirect Main Home Page url to category URL without plugin

Tags: redirect

I am looking for best method without any plugin that will redirect my homepage to category url. e.g

Main page: https://uk49sresult.co.uk/

Direct redirect to this one.

Category URL: https://uk49sresult.co.uk/lunchtime-results/

It helps me to reduce the servers response time.

I have readed many answers but not provided full guideline. Please briefly explain me which code will paste to which file. I have no experience of programming but work a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
add_action( 'request', function( $request ){
    if( empty( $request ) ){
        wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() . '/lunchtime-results/' );
        exit;
    }
    return $request;
});
```

This can be added to your theme's functions.php file.

The code checks the current request arguments. When visiting the home page the request is empty; in all other cases it would include some arguments.

So if the request is empty (is home page) it redirects to a new URL setting the HTTP status to 302(Found).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am also using the "HTTPS" will this code also work for the HTTPS like same in the questions?

Comment: Yes the hook would work the same for HTTP and HTTPS